# Getting output of highstate from python code

Tags: python, salt-stack

I am new to Salt. How do I get the output of state.highstate using python? Can I get the output display as a string using LocalClient? it seems like I need to call salt.output.highstate.output in Salt but how do I do that in python?

Here is what I have tried:

```
import salt.client
local = salt.client.LocalClient()
ret = local.cmd('*', 'output.highstate.output')
```

The return I got back was just saying output.highstate.output is not available. Is there any other way to get output from python code directly?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to interact with Salt from Python.  In general it gives you a generator of dictionaries, it won't format it for you.

The alternate methods don't seem to be documented -- stick with `local.cmd()` if you can.

Here's an example of `cmd_full_return` ([source](http://nullege.com/codes/show/src%40s%40a%40salt-2014.1.3%40salt%40cli%40__init__.py/125/salt.client.LocalClient.cmd_full_return/python)):

## source

```
from pprint import pprint
import salt.client
local = salt.client.LocalClient()
pprint( local.cmd_full_return(
    '*', 'test.ping', verbose=True,
    ) )
```

## output

```
Executing job with jid 20140825132240132013
-------------------------------------------

{'palabras': {'ret': True, 'success': True}}
```

Comment: Thanks, it turned out that I was not seeing the return of the comments I was looking for because I did not set 'verbose = False'. The comments I was looking for have 'result': None.

Comment: Leaving a link to the awesome salt python client documentation here just in case: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/clients/index.html#python-client-api <3